# Cannot get model based test working

Tags: f#, immutability, mutable, fscheck, model-based-testing

As an exercise I wanted to implement a 2-3 finger tree. That should be the perfect opportunity to try out [FsCheck](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/)'s model-based testing. I decided to try the newer [experimental version](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/StatefulTestingNew.html).

So far I only coded one command for the test machine because I already fail at making that work—one the other hand it keeps the post short. The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/CmdQ/23-finger-tree/blob/master/Tests/FingerTreeModelTest.fs).

```
open CmdQ
open Fuchu
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Experimental

type TestType = uint16
type ModelType = ResizeArray<TestType>
type SutType = FingerTree<TestType>

let spec =
    let prepend (what:TestType) =
        { new Operation<SutType, ModelType>() with
            override __.Run model =
                // Also tried returning the same instance.
                let copy = model |> ResizeArray
                copy.Insert(0, what)
                copy

            override __.Check(sut, model) =
                let sutList = sut |> Finger.toList
                let newSut = sut |> Finger.prepend what
                let newSutList = newSut |> Finger.toList
                let modelList = model |> Seq.toList
                let areEqual = newSutList = modelList
                areEqual |@ sprintf "prepend: model = %A, actual = %A (incoming was %A)" modelList newSutList sutList

            override __.ToString() = sprintf "prepend %A" what
        }

    let create (initial:ModelType) =
        { new Setup<SutType, ModelType>() with
            override __.Actual () = initial |> Finger.ofSeq

            override __.Model () = initial //|> ResizeArray // Also tried this.
        }

    let rndNum () : Gen<TestType> = Arb.from<uint16> |> Arb.toGen

    { new Machine<SutType, ModelType>() with
        override __.Setup =
            rndNum()
            |> Gen.listOf
            |> Gen.map ResizeArray
            |> Gen.map create
            |> Arb.fromGen

        override __.Next _ = gen {
            let! cmd = Gen.elements [prepend]
            let! num = rndNum()
            return cmd num
        }
    }

[<Tests>]
let test =
    [spec]
    |> List.map (StateMachine.toProperty >> testProperty "Finger tree")
    |> testList "Model tests"
```

What I understand is this: `Operation<_>.Run` is run twice to build up a `ResizeArray` from one with a single element. Then `Operation<_>.Check` is run twice with the same numbers to insert into a single element `FingerTree<_>`.

The first of the two passes. Single-element tree incoming, adding makes it a (correct) two-element tree which compares well against the model after the first command.

The second command is always the one failing. `Check` is called with the bigger `ResizeList` (now 3 elements) but the same single-element Tree as in the first command. Adding one more element of course does not get it to size 3 and the test fails.

I would have expected that I need to return the updated model from `Check` for the commands to come. But you need to return a `Property` so that's not possible.

Did I completely misunderstand how to approach this? How should a working model-based test be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model-based testing assumes that the "system under test" is modified as a side-effect when `Check` is called on a particular operation, and initialized for that test run when `Setup.Actual()` is called. It is intended for dealing with systems that are mutable - like a mutable object - and that style while somewhat bewildering here works out quite nicely with such systems.

Since your finger tree type is immutable, my advice would be to redefine `SutType` to:

```
type SutType = Ref<FingerTree<TestType>>
```

and modify the rest accordingly.

Comment: Good to know! Is that mentioned in the docs somewhere? Maybe it should be more prominent. Thanks.

Comment: Clearly not prominent enough if you missed it :)