# How do sequence expressions and polymorphic recursion play together?

Tags: f#, seq, recursive-datastructures, parametric-polymorphism, computation-expression

[This project](https://github.com/CmdQ/23-finger-tree/) really is a [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854211/) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976103/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510436/) for me.

I already learned about polymorphic recursion and I understand why it is a special case and therefore F# needs full type annotations.

For regular functions I might need some fiddeling but usually get it right. Now I'm trying to adapt a (working) basic `toSeq` to a more specialized finger tree, but can't.

My feeling is that the use of the computation expression has something to do with it. This is the condensed working version:

```
module ThisWorks =

    module Node =
        type Node<'a> =
            | Node2 of 'a * 'a
            | Node3 of 'a * 'a * 'a

        let toList = function
            | Node2(a, b) -> [a; b]
            | Node3(a, b, c) -> [a; b; c]

    module Digit =
        type Digit<'a> =
            | One of 'a
            | Two of 'a * 'a
            | Three of 'a * 'a * 'a
            | Four of 'a * 'a * 'a * 'a

        let toList = function
            | One a -> [a]
            | Two(a, b) -> [a; b]
            | Three(a, b, c) -> [a; b; c]
            | Four(a, b, c, d) -> [a; b; c; d]

    module FingerTree =
        open Node
        open Digit

        type FingerTree<'a> =
            | Empty
            | Single of 'a
            | Deep of Digit<'a> * Lazy<FingerTree<Node<'a>>> * Digit<'a>

        let rec toSeq<'a> (tree:FingerTree<'a>) : seq<'a> = seq {
            match tree with
            | Single single ->
                yield single
            | Deep(prefix, Lazy deeper, suffix) ->
                yield! prefix |> Digit.toList
                yield! deeper |> toSeq |> Seq.collect Node.toList
                yield! suffix |> Digit.toList
            | Empty -> ()
        }
```

The one I don't manage to get to compile is this:

```
module ThisDoesnt =

    module Monoids =
        type IMonoid<'m> =
            abstract Zero:'m
            abstract Plus:'m -> 'm

        type IMeasured<'m when 'm :> IMonoid<'m>> =
            abstract Measure:'m

        type Size(value) =
            new() = Size 0

            member __.Value = value

            interface IMonoid<Size> with
                member __.Zero = Size()
                member __.Plus rhs = Size(value + rhs.Value)

        type Value<'a> =
            | Value of 'a

            interface IMeasured<Size> with
                member __.Measure = Size 1

    open Monoids

    module Node =
        type Node<'m, 'a when 'm :> IMonoid<'m>> =
            | Node2 of 'm * 'a * 'a
            | Node3 of 'm * 'a * 'a * 'a

        let toList = function
            | Node2(_, a, b) -> [a; b]
            | Node3(_, a, b, c) -> [a; b; c]

    module Digit =
        type Digit<'m, 'a when 'm :> IMonoid<'m>> =
            | One of 'a
            | Two of 'a * 'a
            | Three of 'a * 'a * 'a
            | Four of 'a * 'a * 'a * 'a

        let toList = function
            | One a -> [a]
            | Two(a, b) -> [a; b]
            | Three(a, b, c) -> [a; b; c]
            | Four(a, b, c, d) -> [a; b; c; d]

    module FingerTree =
        open Node
        open Digit

        type FingerTree<'m, 'a when 'm :> IMonoid<'m>> =
            | Empty
            | Single of 'a
            | Deep of 'm * Digit<'m, 'a> * Lazy<FingerTree<'m, Node<'m, 'a>>> * Digit<'m, 'a>

        let unpack (Value v) = v

        let rec toSeq<'a> (tree:FingerTree<Size, Value<'a>>) : seq<'a> = seq {
            match tree with
            | Single(Value single) ->
                yield single
            | Deep(_, prefix, Lazy deeper, suffix) ->
                yield! prefix |> Digit.toList |> List.map unpack

                #if ITERATE
                for (Value deep) in toSeq deeper do
                                    ^^^^^
                    yield deep

                #else

                yield! deeper |> toSeq |> Seq.collect (Node.toList >> List.map unpack)
                                 ^^^^^
                #endif

                yield! suffix |> Digit.toList |> List.map unpack
            | Empty -> ()
        }
```

The error message I get says

> Error     Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       FingerTree<Size,Node<Size,Value<'a>>> -> 'b
>   but given a
>       FingerTree<Size,Value<'c>> -> seq<'c>
>   The type 'Node<Size,Value<'a>>' does not match the type 'Value<'b>'

and the squiggles underline the recursive call of `toSeq`.

I know that the “deeper” type is encapsulated in a `Node` and in the working code I just unpack it afterwards. But here the compiler trips already before I get the chance to unpack. Trying a `for (Value deep) in toSeq deeper do yield deep` has the same problem.

<s>I already have a way out, namely to use the `toSeq` of the “base” `Tree` and `Seq.map unpack` afterwards.</s> Not true, trying that yields a very similar error message.

I'm curious what makes this code break and how it could be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler's error message seems clear to me: `toSeq` is applicable only to values of type `FingerTree<Size, Value<'a>>` for some `'a`, but you're trying to call it on a value of type `FingerTree<Size,Node<Size,Value<'a>>>` instead, which is not compatible.  There's nothing specific to polymorphic recursion or sequence expressions, these types just don't match.

Instead, it seems like it would be much simpler to make `toSeq` more generic by taking an input of type `FingerTree<Size, 'a>` (without any reference to `Value`), which would enable the recursive call you want.  Then you can easily derive the more specific function you actually want by composing the more general `toSeq` with `Seq.map unpack`.